# how does the short(vector.size()) command conversion work in C++?

Tags: c++

I don't know any other way to return the size of a vector other than the `.size()` command, and it works very well, but, it return a variable of type `long long unsigned int`, and this in very cases are very good, but I'm sure my program will never have a vector so big that it need all that size of return, `short int` is more than enough.
I know, for today's computers those few enused bytes are irrelevant, but I don't like to leave these "loose ends" even if they are small, and whem I was programming, I came across some details that bothered me.

Look at these examples:

```
for(short int X = 0 ; X < Vector.size() ; X++){
     
}
```

compiling this, I receive this warning:

`warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'short int' and 'std::vector<unsigned char>::size_type' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]|`

this is because the `.size()` return value type is different from the `short int` I'm compiling, "X" is a `short int`, and `Vector.size()` return a `long long unsigned int`, was expected, so if I do this:

```
for(size_t X = 0 ; X < Vector.size() ; X++){
     
}
```

the problem is gone, but by doing this, I'm creating a `long long unsigned int` in variable `size_t` and I'm returning another variable long long unsigned int, so, my computer allocale two variables `long long unsigned int`, so, what I do for returning a simple `short int`? I don't need anything more than this, long long unsigned int is overkill, so I did this:

```
for(short int X = 0 ; X < short(Vector.size()) ; X++){
     
}
```

but... how is this working? `short int X = 0` is allocating a short int, nothing new, but what about `short (Vector.size())`, is the computer allocating a long unsigned int and converting it to a short int? or is the compiler "changing" the return of the `.size()` function by making it naturally return a short int and, in this case, not allocating a `long long unsined int`? because I know the compilers are responsible for optimizing the code too, is there any "problem" or "detail" when using this method? since I rarely see anyone using this, what exactly is this `short()` doing in memory allocation? where can i read more about it?

(thanks to everyone who responded)

Comment: .size() allocates nothing, it returns value of type size_t.

Comment: On the other hand, the value returned by .size is contained in a variable of the type size_t and you can't reduce it unless you implement your own container.

Comment: Note that your CPU's register will almost certainly be **bigger** than a `short int`. It's not a matter of "wasted (data) bytes", it's a matter of "extra code needed to zero out the high bits to simulate wrap-around". It could very well be a pessimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget for a moment that this involves a `for` loop; that's important for the underlying code, but it's a distraction from what's going on with the conversion.

```
short X = Vector.size();
```

That line calls `Vector.size()`, which returns a value of type `std::size_t`. `std::size_t` is an unsigned type, large enough to hold the size of any object. So it could be `unsigned long`, or it could be `unsigned long long`. In any event, it's definitely not `short`. So the compiler has to **convert** that value to `short`, and that's what it does.

Most compilers these days don't trust you to understand what this actually does, so they warn you. (Yes, I'm rather opinionated about compilers that nag; that doesn't change the analysis here). So if you want to see that warning (i.e., you don't turn it off), you'll see it. If you want to write code that doesn't generate that warning, then you have to change the code to say "yes, I know, and I really mean it". You do that with a **cast**:

```
short X = short(Vector.size());
```

The cast tells the compiler to call `Vector.size()` and convert the resulting value to `short`. The code then assigns the result of that conversion to `X`. So, more briefly, in this case it tells the compiler that you want it to do exactly what it would have done without the cast. The difference is that because you wrote a cast, the compiler won't warn you that you might not know what you're doing.

Some folks prefer to write that cast is with a `static_cast`:

```
short X = static_cast<short>(Vector.size());
```

That does the same thing: it tells the compiler to do the conversion to `short` and, again, the compiler won't warn you that you did it.

In the original `for` loop, a different conversion occurs:

```
X < Vector.size()
```

That bit of code calls `Vector.size()`, which still returns an unsigned type. In order to compare that value with `X`, the two sides of the `<` have to have the same type, and the rules for this kind of expression require that `X` gets promoted to `std::size_t`, i.e., that the value of `X` gets treated as an unsigned type. That's okay as long as the value isn't negative. If it's negative, the conversion to the unsigned type is okay, but it will produce results that probably aren't what was intended. Since we know that `X` is not negative here, the code works perfectly well.

But we're still in the territory of compiler nags: since `X` is signed, the compiler warns you that promoting it to an unsigned type might do something that you don't expect. Again, you know that that won't happen, but the compiler doesn't trust you. So you have to insist that you know what you're doing, and again, you do that with a cast:

```
X < short(Vector.size())
```

Just like before, that cast converts the result of calling `Vector.size()` to `short`. Now both sides of the `<` are the same type, so the `<` operation doesn't require a conversion from a signed to an unsigned type, so the compiler has nothing to complain about. There is still a conversion, because the rules say that values of type `short` get promoted to `int` in this expression, but don't worry about that for now.

Another possibility is to use an unsigned type for that loop index:

```
for (unsigned short X = 0; X < Vector.size(); ++X)
```

But the compiler might still insist on warning you that not all values of type `std::size_t` can fit in an `unsigned short`. So, again, you might need a cast. Or change the type of the index to match what the compiler think you need:

```
for (std::size_t X = 0; X < Vector.size(); ++X_
```

If I were to go this route, I would use `unsigned int` and if the compiler insisted on telling me that I don't know what I'm doing I'd yell at the compiler (which usually isn't helpful) and then I'd turn off that warning. There's really no point in using `short` here, because the loop index will always be converted to `int` (or `unsigned int`) wherever it's used. It will probably be in a register, so there is no space actually saved by storing it as a `short`.

Even better, as recommended in other answers, is to use a range-base for loop, which avoids managing that index:

```
for (auto& value: Vector) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In all cases, `X` has a storage duration of automatic, and the result of `Vector.size()` does not outlive the full expression where it is created.

> I don't need anything more than this, long long unsigned int is overkill

Typically, automatic duration variables are "allocated" either on the stack, or as registers. In either case, there is no performance benefit to decreasing the allocation size, and there can be a performance *penalty* in narrowing and then widening values.

In the very common case where you are using `X` solely to index into `Vector`, you should strongly consider using a different kind of `for`:

```
for (auto & value : Vector) {
    // replace Vector[X] with value in your loop body
}
```